# Access Hazelcast maps directly from Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hazelcast, vert.x

I'm using Vertx with Hazelcast and I would like to consume my cluster's maps directly from an Ionic App. I know how to setup a bridge between my app and the eventbus, but that does only give me access to the event bus. I didn't find a way to directly access my cluster manager in order to register listeners on the different maps.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this. You need to implement a server-side component which:

1/ registers a listener on the Hazelcast map

```
IMap<String, String> map = hz.getMap("somemap");
map.addEntryListener(new MyEntryListener(), true);
```

2/ forwards map notifications to the eventbus

```
@Override
public void entryAdded(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
  // Transform the HZ event into something usable by the browser (eg JSON object)
  JsonObject json = eventToJson(event)
  vertx.eventBus().send("somemap-entry-added", json);
}
```

Comment: I understand this might be the only way. The problem with this is that, in my case, I would have to register a consumer on the event bus for each user logged in the app in order to send a message to each of them individually. In my head, this doesn't sound like a scalable solution. However, your post answers my question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with registering a consumer for each user. If you `eventBus#publish` instead of `#send`, they will have receive the messages.

Comment: Yes, I can use `publish` but it is not the intended behavior. My concern is more related to the number of active connections (consumers) that the event bus can handle. But I guess that would depend on the size of my cluster, am I right?

Comment: The eventbus bridge should be able to handle a great number of concurrent connections. Give it a try and measure

Comment: Thank you for your help, @tsegismont :)